# Eclipse/Java class couldnt be found

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java and have some basic problem. Would appreciate your help guys.
I try to run a `HelloWorld` program but having an error:

> "Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld".

I noticed that `Eclipse` saves the project in parallel virtual store directory and not the one I mentioned.
When I manually move the project to `Eclipse_Workspace` directory it works just fine. What should I do for `Eclipse` to save the files correctly?!

If needed:
I downloaded `JDK 1.8.0_51` for `Win 32` and `Eclipse IDE for Java developers (Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1))`. `Win7 32 Ultimate`.
I added a `Path` value in System Variables -

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin

Default Resource Path in Eclipse is:

> C:\Program Files\Java\Eclipse_Workspace

Thanks

Comment: See the package declarations in the java files.

Answer (score 0):

VladBio,

Make sure the following environment variables set correctly:

**JAVA_HOME** = jdk root folder (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51)

**Path** = jdk bin folder (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin)

To test this go into your **cmd** (Start -> run -> cmd) and type:

`java -version`

*C:>java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)*

If you see the correct version then the issue is in Eclipse.

In Eclipse you can check your JDK settings in Windows -> Preferences -> Installed JREs. Your correct JDK should be listed there.

On Eclipse you can also have project specific java version.
Right click on your project -> properties. On Library tab you should see something like **JRE System Library [jdk1.8.0_45]**

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean) for a more detailed answer of what could be going wrong.

I Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.
I suppose I figured this out.
It was a problem in eclipse - it couldnt automatically make a changes in java directory because any change there is allowed only with admin approval.
I changed the path in eclipse to a folder on my desktop. It solved out the problem.
BTW I tried what you said and the output in cmd was identical to yours.
Thanks again